# Set value of Input type month

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm processing a creditcard swipe and retrieving the data and display it on my input fields. I have three actually. Cardnumber, expiration date and name on card.

I was able to display the data of cardnumber and name by using this

```
$("#cardnumber").val( result.cardnumber );
$("#name").val( result.name );
```

My question is how would i do it on a input field which type is set to month?

i tried this but doesn't work `$("#expdate").val( result.date )` the data for the expiration date is in the format of `YY/MM or 12/08`

**UPDATE:**

sorry the data for the date i'm receiving is in this format 1208 instead of 12/08

HTML

```
<input type="month" id="expDate" value="" />
```

Comment: What is the `HTML` of the input type month? post that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you post it seems

```
$("#expdate")
```

should be

```
$("#expDate")
```

Its a typos.

#### According to edit

*if you date is always in format `ddmm` then following will work:*

```
var x = result.date;
$("#expDate").val( x.substr(0,2) + '/' + x.substr(2) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Split it on the year/month-separator and use only the second part of the operation.

```
$("#expDate").val( result.date.split('/')[1] )
```

Given your edit, you may instead want to use `substring` to skip the first two characters:

```
$("#expDate").val( result.date.substring(2) )
```